# Extending Zend DB Table to include BETWEEN and LIMIT

Tags: sql, zend-db

Am looking for how I can extend the Zend_DB_Table below to accomodate a BETWEEN two dates syntax and LIMIT syntax

My current construct is

```
class Model_DbTable_Tablelist extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'mytable';

    $select = $this->select()
                    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                    ->from('mytable',
                        array('MyCol1', 'MyDate'));

}
```

I want it extended to be equivalent to the query below

```
SELECT MyCol1,MyDate FROM mytable
WHERE MyDate BETWEEN '2008-04-03' AND '2009-01-02'
LIMIT 0,20
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding BETWEEN, [this issue](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2211) was reported on the Zend site - it appears to still be open.  The workaround mentioned is to use something like

```
$this->where('MyDate > ?', '2008-04-03')->where('MyDate < ?', '2009-01-02');
```

Looks like you can use the "limit" method to add a LIMIT clause to your SQL, e.g.

```
->limit(0, 20);
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: "This is equivalent to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max) if all the arguments are of the same type." So in your query you need use "=" sign too!

Answer (score 1):

$adapter = $this->getAdapter();

$dt = "datetime between ? and ? ";
$dt = $adapter->quoteInto($dt, "04-01-2010 ", null, 1);
$dt = $adapter->quoteInto($dt, "05-01-2010 ", null, 1);
$this->where($dt)

Answer (score 0):

Note that ->limit(0,20) means no limit to the number of returned rows, but skip the first 20 rows.